# DAX calculate which patients have lapsed in a given time period

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying calculated the number patients who have lapsed in a given time period, e.g. last week (which uses a date filter linked to the All Dates table).

Patients become lapsed after 2 years of not visiting. I have the following DAX code:

```
CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(vw_VisitsDentist[PracticeIDPatientID]), FILTER(ALL('All Dates'), 'All Dates'[Date] >= MIN('All Dates'[Date]) - 730 && 'All Dates'[Date] <= MAX('All Dates'[Date]) - 730))
```

This is giving me incorrect results; what should I have instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
CALCULATE(
  DISTINCTCOUNT(vw_VisitsDentist[PracticeIDPatientID]),
  DATESINPERIOD('All Dates'[Date], MAX('All Dates'[Date]), -2, YEAR)
)
```

Will give you the number of patients who **have visited** from the filtered/sliced date to 2 years from then.